# Less CSS inlining error

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail, less-compilation

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p1 with claue theme.
I am getting below error in transactional email, how to fix it?
 `Compilation from source: LESS file is empty: frontend/Mgs/claue/en_US/css/email-inline.less`

Comment: check this link --- https://reroottechnotes.wordpress.com/2018/01/24/magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below commands resolved the error.
Deploy mode set to Default
`bin/magento deploy:mode:set default`
Upgraded setup
`bin/magento setup:upgrade`
Deployed static content
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`